# How do I permanently enlarge curs3

Tags: cursor

Each time I boot up my laptop I go to Unity tweaks cursor,tick box to enable large cursor and get a large cursor which stays for whole session,fine! Unfortunately it reverts to a small cursor every time I log on, how can I make it stay large, very grateful for any suggestions